# Have any rabbinic organizations taken a public position on Rabbi Daniel Landes's Yashrut institute?

Tags: orthodox, semicha

Have any mainstream Orthodox rabbis or rabbinical bodies, either in Israel or the United States, expressed an opinion (pro or con) on the Yashrut institute, established by Rabbi Daniel Landes?  I am trying to get a sense of how their *semicha* is regarded in the broader Orthodox world. In particular, does the mainstream Orthodox world regard rabbis ordained by Yashrut as "Orthodox Rabbis"?

Obviously the answer to this is: it depends on who you ask.  So in order to make this question answerable (and not just opinion-based), I'm asking if there have been any public statements to this effect. (For comparison, I am thinking of the public denunciations that [some Rabbis](https://www.jta.org/2013/09/30/united-states/agudath-israel-condemns-chovevei-torah-for-multidenominational-roundtable) have issued regarding Yeshivat Chovevei Torah, a somewhat analogous "progressive Orthodox" institution.)

Comment: For context he somewhat recently gave semicha to a man specifically because he was in a public relationship with another man and no one else would grant him semicha.

Comment: Does the OP agree with the edit?

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, it's fine. I'm assuming there will be great variation among different streams of Orthodoxy, and don't want to limit my question only to Modern Orthodox authorities (but I don't want to exclude them either).

Comment: Would someone care to explain the reason for the downvote? Is there something I can do to improve the question?

Comment: As you noted, many Orthodox rabbis have denounced YCT. A YCT ordination is insufficient to be accepted into the Rabbinical Council of America, which is affiliated with the Union of Orthodox Jewish Congregations of America. As Landes will ordain people that YCT won't, I'd imagine his ordinations to become even less accepted than those of YCT. An interesting question is whether those with Landes' ordination will be accepted into the International Rabbinic Fellowship, which comprises mostly YCT graduates.